# Active Admin: Add Entries to report

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

So what I have is a report model and an entries model. The report has many entries and entries belong to the report. What I am wanting to do is be able to click a button on the show page of the report and add new entries. Is there a way of doing this? A non-ajax solution is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cocoon` is an excellent gem for this.

It gives you a `Remove` button for each entry and an `Add` button to add as many entries as you want.  Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries` to your Report model. You need to put the entries form in their own partial but that's not a hardship, and cocoon automatically creates the show/hide jquery for you.  Be sure to include and whitelist the entries' `id` column as a hidden field otherwise you can end up with duplicate entries, and you also need to whitelist `_delete` (that's underscore + delete) so that the entries can be deleted by rails when required.